# Why can't we apply L'Hospital's rule to sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am reading this from my text and I don't really understand why we can't apply L'Hospital's rule directly to sequences?

[image]

I read this theorem and I get it:

[image]

Comment: What is the derivative of a sequence?

Comment: a sequence is defined as a function $s: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$. there is no derivative of such function.

Comment: Can I ask what textbook is it? I am interest in it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the idea of proposing to use L'Hopital's rule for sequences is based on the belief that if $f(n)\rightarrow L$ then $f(x) \rightarrow L$.

This doesn't hold true actually, see this counter-example:

$$f(n)=cos(2n\pi)$$

Trivially we can see that $f(n)=1$  $\forall n$, so $f(n) \rightarrow 1$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$.

This doesn't hold true for $f(x) = cos(2x\pi)$ since it doesn't converge when $x\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: So is my textbook wrong?

Comment: Your textbook is right, it shows the implication the other way, what holds true for the function, holds true for the sequence but not the other way around.

Comment: @KittyCapital The textbook has another stategy. The "counterexample" above says that "sequence converges $\implies$ function converges" is not always true; but "function converges $\implies$ sequence converges" is true. And this is what the textbook did.

Comment: @st.math, then according to the book's example, it's like using L'Hospital's rule in the sequence directly at the end?