# How do I evaluate this limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{p}{n}e^{it/n}}{1-(1-\frac{p}{n})e^{it/n}}$?

Tags: calculus, probability, limits

I am having trouble with the following limit arising from a probability exercise. Let $0\le p\le1, n\in  \mathbb{N}$

$\forall t \in \mathbb{R}$

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{p}{n}e^{it/n}}{1-(1-\frac{p}{n})e^{it/n}}$

I get an indeterminate form 0/0. Since it is a limit of a sequence, I don't think I can use L'Hopital or a Taylor series expansion. Any idea ? I am supposed to find $\frac{p}{p-it}, \forall t \in \mathbb{R}$

---

Edit Following J.G.'s suggestion

$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{pxe^{itx}}{1-(1-px)e^{itx}}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{px}{e^{-itx}-(1-px)}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{p}{-ite^{-itx}+p}=\frac{p}{p-it}$

Comment: The denominator goes to $1-e^{it}$ as $n\to\infty$

Comment: @KentaS I am sorry there was a typo

Comment: Hint: if you can prove $\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{pxe^{itx}}{1-(1-px)e^{itx}}$ exists, that will be your desired limit. So try L'Hôpital's rule on that.

Comment: @J.G. I had tried that, that is I did  x=1/n and got that expresion, but it seems to me that x is still taking discrete values.I don't know how to giustify x becomes real

Comment: You could also use Taylor with $e^{(it/n)}=1+\frac{it}{n}+O(n^2)$.

Comment: What I'm suggesting is proving the stronger result that the continuous-$x$ limit exists. By the way, the calculation is easier if you multiply top & bottom by $e^{-itx}$ first.

Comment: @J.G. I did it,see the edit. how can that imply the wanted limit?

Comment: Sorry, you miscalculated. The exponent is $itx$, not $ipx$ or $px$.

Comment: @J.G. Fixed that, back to the previous question

Comment: That the continuous case proves the discrete one follows from their formal definitions. Since the continuous one-sided limit in $x$ exists,  $\forall\epsilon>0\exists\delta_\epsilon>0\forall x(0<x<\delta_\epsilon\implies|f(x)-L|<\epsilon)$. The cases $\epsilon=1/n$ give the discrete limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would multiply top and bottom by $e^{-it/n}$ to get

$$\frac{ \frac{p}{n}}{ e^{-it/n}-(1-\frac{p}{n})}.$$

Then multiply top and bottom by $n$ to get

$$\frac{p}{ne^{-it/n}-(n-p)} = \frac{p}{n(e^{-it/n}-1)+p}.$$

So the problem boils down to finding

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} n(e^{-it/n}-1) = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(e^{-it/n}-1) }{\frac{1}{n}} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(1 -\frac{it}{n}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{(it^2)}{n^2}-\cdots)-1}{\frac{1}{n}}.$$

using the Taylor series for $e^x.$  Cancel the $1$'s  and multiply top and bottom by $n$ to get

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}  (-it + \frac{1}{2}\frac{(it)^2}{n} -\cdots) = -it.$$

Comment: Isn't taylor series only valid in the continuum? For a fixed $t$, $-it/n$ takes discrete values and that is what is bothering me.

Comment: @mathlover Well, it shouldn't be. The continuous limit implies the discrete limit, as I've explained. It's the other direction you have to be careful about.

Comment: If $\lim f(x) = L$ then $\lim f(n) =L.$  The other way doesn't work, as $f(x) = \sin \pi x$ demonstrates.

Comment: @J.G. If every time I have a discrete limit, I can just do  the continuous limit and the answer is also the discrete limit, then when would one ever need to find a discrete limit directly? And is it possible to do it?

Comment: @J.G. I've been reading some posts that people say you can't use L'Hopital Rule with sequences, why is that if  using the fact that the continuous limit implies the discrete one, I could just go and use L'hopital directly pretending I am in the continuum

Comment: See this question:  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3158665/362009

Comment: @B.Goddard I read that, but still think that if I have to find the limit for a sequence, ok I cannot apply L'Hospital , but I apply L'Hospital for the continuous limit and then go back to the sequence just to give the answer, since what holds in the continuous, holds in the discrete. I don't think I am using the converse false implication. It's like your method of proving a stronger statement in the continuous and then the weaker discrete one holds

Comment: I am talking about the post' example $\lim_{n \to +\infty} \ln n/n$

Comment: @mathlover Sorry, I had to go offline for a while. The crucial point is that, because (i) the existence of a continuous limit is a stronger result and (ii) if this holds the discrete limit exists and is the same, we're in luck if the continuous limit does in fact exist. The reason you have to be careful is because sadly sometimes it doesn't. In that case, you need to do something different to compute (not to mention check the existence of) the discrete limit. Sometimes, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz-Cesaro_theorem) will help.

Comment: Does $o(-it/n)$ make sense to write it in the taylor expansion instead of the "..."?. That is, using complex numbers with little o?